# Make `thing-at-point` treat dot as a symbol-constituent character?

Tags: syntax-table, thing-at-point

Is there a way to tweak `thing-at-point` symbol regexp, so that it ignore dots as separators? Right now `foo.bar` in my Emacs is recognized as two different symbols, where I wish it was one.

Comment: See also [Why does thing-at-point not consider plus as a filename character?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/33440/260)

Answer (score 3):

To supplement what @phils said -

Make `.` have symbol-constituent syntax in the current syntax table, or in a copy of it.

Either define your own replacement function for `thing-at-point`:

```el
(defun my-thg-at-pt (thing &optional no-properties)
  "..."
  (let ((stab  (copy-syntax-table)))
    (with-syntax-table stab
      (modify-syntax-entry ?. "_")
      (thing-at-point thing no-properties))))
```

or wrap whatever code calls `thing-at-point` similarly.  For instance, if you call some function `foo` that you cannot modify, which calls `thing-at-point`, then wrap your call to `foo` similarly:

```el
(let ((stab  (copy-syntax-table)))
  (with-syntax-table stab
    (modify-syntax-entry ?. "_")
    ...
    (foo)))
```

Of course, if `foo` does other stuff, and some of that depends on `.` *NOT* having symbol syntax, then wrapping all of `foo` this way is too unfocused.

Answer (score 1):

That's dependent on the syntax table for the buffer in question.  In elisp, for instance, `foo.bar` *is* treated as a single symbol.

You can specify that `.` is symbol-constituent in the current buffer's syntax table with:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?. "_")
```

Unless this is for a custom mode of your own devising, I would suggest that you try to establish if there is a sensible reason *why* `.` was not already symbol-constituent.